# Programmatically select a value using the Id retrieved via ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to ask you how to programmatically select a value using the Id retrieved via ajax call. Following the select2 guide I used the following code

```
$ ('# select2_id'). Val ('1');
$ ('# select2_id'). trigger ('change');
```

but the field remains empty! I think it's because the options are loaded only when the ajax call starts on the click of select2. Can you suggest me a way to solve?

Te code to initialize the select2 for large options (about 2000 options):

```
$("#select2_id").select2({
        ajax:{
            url: '/url/getCompanyType',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function(params){
                return{
                    _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                    search: params.term
                }
            },
            processResults: function(response){
                return{
                    results: response
                }
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? What do you mean by "the field remains empty"? Have you checked whether select2 throws any error messages?

Comment: select2 dowsn't return error. The serch of the options works perfectly. But I need to show the field with a pre selected value. The selected2 is placed in a view to modify data of a specific company. So I need to compile the selected2 with the specific value

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as the syntax is incorrect:

```
$ ('# select2_id'). Val ('1');
$ ('# select2_id'). trigger ('change');
```

This would work:

```
$('#select2_id').val('1');
$('#select2_id').trigger('change');
```

The casing of variable names is not arbitrary: it can have an effect on the code.

```js
// this works:
const obj1 = {key1:'val1'}
console.log(obj1.key1)

// and this too:
const obj2 = { key2: 'val2' }
console.log( obj2.key2 )

// but this does not:
const obj3 = { key3: 'val3' }
console.log(obj3.Key3) // see the different casing?
```

So, returning to your example, the snippet below

- has a `select` that is not controlled (to show the default behavior)
- has a `select` that is controlled by JS (to show that it works)

```js
$('#select2_id').val('1');
// actually, you don't need the trigger, as the
// .val('newVal') SETS the value of the select
// $('#select2_id').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="not_controlled_id">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<br />
<select id="select2_id">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```